# Apache Http Client and Load Balancers

Tags: java, httpclient, load-balancing, apache-httpclient-4.x

After spending a few hours reading the Http Client documentation and source code I have decided that I should definitely ask for help here.

I have a load balancer server using a round-robin algorithm somewhat like this

`+---> RESTServer1 
client --> load balancer +---> RESTServer2
                         +---> RESTServer3`

Our client is using HttpClient to direct requests to our load balancer server, which in turn round-robins the requests to the corresponding RESTServer.

Now, Apache HttpClient creates, by default, [a pool of connections](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) (2 per route by default). This connections are by default persistent connections since I am using Http v1.1 and my servers are emitting Connection: Keep-Alive headers.

So, the problems is that since HttpClient creates this persistent connections, then those connections are no longer subject to round-robing algorithm at the balancer level. They always hit the same server every time.

This creates two problems:

1. I can see that sometimes one or more of the balanced servers are overloaded with traffic, whereas one ore more of the other servers are idle; and
2. even if I take one of my REST servers out of the balancer, it stills receives requests while the persistent connections are alive.

Definitely this is not the intended behavior.

I suppose I could force a `Connection: close` header in my responses, or I could run HttpClient without a connection pool or with a [NoConnectionReuseStrategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/ConnectionReuseStrategy.html?is-external=true). But [the documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) for HttpClient states that the idea behind the use of a pool is to improve performance by avoiding having to open a socket every time and doing all the TPC handshaking and related stuff. So, I have to conclude that the use of a connection pool is beneficial to the performance of my applications.

So my question here, is there a way to use persistent connections with a load-balancer in the way or am I forced to use non-persistent connections for this scenario?

I want the performance that comes with reusing connections, but I want them properly load-balanced. Any thoughts on how I can configure this scenario with Apache Http Client if at all possible?

Comment: I believe you can configure that in the balancer. That's the right place to get your hands dirty with in order to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is perhaps more related to your load balancer configuration and the style of load balancing. There are several ways:

1. HTTP Redirection
2. LB acts as a reverse proxy
3. Pure packet forwarding

In scenarios 1 and 3 you do not have a chance with persistent connections. If your load balancer acts like a reverse proxy, there might be a way to achieve persistent connections with balancing. "Dumb" balancers, like SMTP or LDAP selects the target per TCP connection, not on a request basis.

For example the Apache HTTPd server with the balancer module (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) can dispatch every request (even on persistent connections) to a different server.

Also check, that you do not receive a balancer cookie which might be session persistent so that the cause is not the persistent connection but a balancer cookie.

HTH, Mark

Comment: This is a pretty good lead. We are using F5 LB, and I just found [this link](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/persistent-and-persistence-whats-the-difference) that seems to describe what you mention in your answer.

Comment: Do you mean "packet forwarding"?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @mp911de answer

One can also make the scenarios 1 and 3 work reasonably well by limiting the total time to live of persistent connections to some short period time, say 15 seconds. This way connections would live long enough to get re-used during periods of activity and short enough to go away during periods of relative inactivity.